# Integrate $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-\frac{1}{2}(ax^2 + \beta x + \gamma)}N(\delta x + \epsilon)dx$

Tags: improper-integrals, gaussian-integral

I am trying to do some practice questions with respect to properties of the gaussian distribution:

$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-\frac{1}{2}(ax^2 + \beta x + \gamma)}N(\delta x + \epsilon)dx$

where $N(y) = \frac{1}{ \sqrt{2 \pi}} \int_{-\infty}^{y}e^{-x^{2}/2}$. I am provided with a hint to differentiate by $\epsilon$

I would greatly appreciate it if someone could help me.

Thanks

Comment: Your title and your text disagree on whether $N$ is in the exponent or not.

Comment: What happened when you applied the hint? What, you did not even try? Second mystery: are you able to prove the identity stated in the answer you accepted? Hmmm...

Comment: Why should I answer your (new) question if you do not even bother to answer mine?

Comment: Please do not deface your question, this kind of behaviour is frowned upon on the site. And in case you would be preparing to erase your traces here, be aware this is even more frowned upon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the suggestion, differentiate this expression with respect to $\epsilon$ to get

$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp\left(-\tfrac{1}{2}(ax^{2}+bx+c+(\delta x+\epsilon)^{2})\right)\mathrm{d}x
=\frac{\exp\left(-\frac{1}{2}c-\frac{1}{2}\epsilon^2+\frac{(b+2\delta\epsilon)^{2}}{8a+8\delta^{2}}\right)}{\sqrt{a+\delta^{2}}}
$$

Integrate with respect to $\epsilon$ and use either of the values at $\epsilon\rightarrow\pm\infty$. You will be able to write the result in terms of the $N$ function you defined.